# How to get a while loop to work with a number generator?

Tags: c++

So for my exercise, I have to generate a random number between 1 and 100 using the srand function. And I got that part to work, but then I have to add a loop so that users can guess again if they didn't get it right on the first try. I can't seem to make the while loop work.

I'm writing the code on text edit and using Xcode as a compiler through the terminal app on mac. And I'm doing my best using the programming terminology--I'm new so if anything sounds off, that's why.

```
int main()
{
  srand(time(0));
  int randomNumber = 1 + (rand() % 100);
  int humanGuess;


  while (true)
  {
    cout << "Guess a number between 1 and 100!" << endl; 
    cin >> humanGuess;
    cin.ignore(1000, 10);

    if (humanGuess == randomNumber) break; 
    cout << "Great job. You got it! It's " << randomNumber << endl; 

    if (humanGuess >= randomNumber)
    cout << "Too high. Try again!" << endl;

    if (humanGuess <= randomNumber)
    cout << "Too low. Try again!" << endl;
  }//while 
}
```

There is no error message, but it's not compiling right. This is what I keep getting when I run it on Terminal:

```
Guess a number between 1 and 100!
23
Great job. You got it! It's 55
Too low. Try again!
Guess a number between 1 and 100!
78
Great job. You got it! It's 55
Too high. Try again!
Guess a number between 1 and 100!
```

Comment: If it builds (without warnings, always add flags for extra warnings) then it is "compiling right". You have a logical error in the program code, and to find and solve that you need to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: As a hint, put the `break` statement on its own line, and indent it properly. Then some [rubber-duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) should be all you need.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude haha thanks for that first link--probably definitely something I need. Alright, lemme go through it again

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude okay so I played with it and somehow got it to work using else if and I put the break statement on it's own line. But I still don't understand why the break statement needs to go on its line--many examples I looked at shows it on the same line as the condition. Why is this?? If you have time to respond, that'll be great. If not, it's cool too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code, as shown in the question is (with the `break` on its own line)

```
if (humanGuess == randomNumber)
    break;

cout << "Great job. You got it! It's " << randomNumber << endl;
```

If the condition `humanGuess == randomNumber` is true, you break out of the loop with the `break` statement. Otherwise you *unconditionally* print `"Great job..."`.

You need to put the printing as a part of the body of the `if` statement, and `break` after you print:

```
if (humanGuess == randomNumber)
{
    cout << "Great job. You got it! It's " << randomNumber << endl; 
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are breaking too early. Try moving the break after the print out. Also it costs nothing in performance to initialise numbers to a known state, it's good practice to, not because there's anything wrong with this code, but if there is additional code inserted that relies on the humanGuess variable - say, then this may not always be the same value.

```
int main(){
  srand(time(0));
  int randomNumber = 1 + (rand() % 100);
  int humanGuess=0;

  while (true){

    cout << "Guess a number between 1 and 100!" << endl; 
    cin >> humanGuess;
    cin.ignore(1000, 10);

    if (humanGuess == randomNumber){  
       cout << "Great job. You got it! It's " << randomNumber << endl; 
       break;
    }    

    if (humanGuess >= randomNumber)
    cout << "Too high. Try again!" << endl;

    if (humanGuess <= randomNumber)
    cout << "Too low. Try again!" << endl;
  }//while 
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't putting the rand() function inside the loop make it impossible for the user to try guessing again on the same loop? I only tell them what the answer is if they got it right.

Comment: Well I guess that's true.

Comment: Okay let's get that changed.

Comment: I see where you're coming from tho. I think your point on putting the srand in the loop would make for a good companion program so that users can get new numbers generated each time they guess wrong. Anyway, thank you. Much obliged